# How to make a lingering potion stay longer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

Im wanting to make a gas chamber (for my horror puzzle map) and I want to add a lingering potion to stay for ever and do damage is there a way I can do this? I'm fine with using redstone or commands.

Answer (score 1):

You use glow stone dust to make it longer, but I don't think you can make it last forever.

Comment: Glowstone changes the strength of the potion and shortens the time. Redstone dust causes the potion to last longer. Additionally, this would not cause the potion to last forever, only a bit longer. And on top of that, using commands it is possible to create a potion that lasts virtually forever.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Make it drop a lingering potion, then use a /effect to give them the same effect, but for a long period of time (10000000 or longer).
   In order to do this, do /effect give @a  100000000  false
2. Make a custom potion through commands that has a near infinite length.
   In order to do this, do /give @p minecraft:lingering_potion{Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:"minecraft:",Duration:100000000000}],display:{Name:""}}. You can change  to the effect of your choice, and set the name to whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a torture chamber, you could use commands to give wither to every player within an area (area of the chamber)

If you want partices, use repeating command blocks to generate particlues

Remember to use unconditional repeating command blocks